# Why is DBAL returning a SQL Syntax Error?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 along with CodeIgniter.

I'm having a query in some of my functions that trigger a SQL Error. And I can't find the reason why

The function is the following:

```
private function _key_exists($key)
    {
        $this->CI->load->library('doctrine');
        $em = $this->CI->doctrine->em;
        echo "<br />Key : ".$key;

        $key_object = $em->getRepository( 'Entity\Key' )->findOneBy( array( 'key' => $key ) );

        if( $key_object )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        // return $this->db->where(config_item('rest_key_column'), $key)->count_all_results(config_item('rest_keys_table')) > 0;
    }
```

When Key ENtity is :

```
<?php

namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Keys
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="keys")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Key
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="key", type="string", length=40, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $key;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ignore_limits", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $ignoreLimits;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_private_key", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $isPrivateKey;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ip_addresses", type="text", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $ipAddresses;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_created", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $dateCreated;

/* Getters and Setters ... */

}
```

And the error message is :

> Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing
>   'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.key AS key2, t0.level AS level3,
>   t0.ignore_limits AS ignore_limits4, t0.is_private_key AS
>   is_private_key5, t0.ip_addresses AS ip_addresses6, t0.date_created AS
>   date_created7 FROM keys t0 WHERE t0.key = ? LIMIT 1' with params
>   {"1":"0fedfa4d50653317df76a4dba79f9f07cd7a8273"}: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'keys t0 WHERE t0.key =
>   '0fedfa4d50653317df76a4dba79f9f07cd7a8273' LIMIT 1' at line 1 in
>   E:\Programmes\wamp\www\myapp\application\libraries\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php
>   on line 47

I do see : `Key : c242c67787bd0b9a9b11a54fc942fde50f099235` in the output though

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the right sql code?  Is your User entity stored in a table called keys?

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, if you need to share doctrine entities then switch to yaml which bypasses the whole orm issue.  I have used D2 for about 4 years now (alpha versions) and it's very stable.

Comment: Thanks man, you're completely right, this is not the syntax that cause this issue, let me update the question in a second. Many thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: So my understanding is that it is somehow looking for a key t0 table (near 'keys t0 WHERE t0.key =' is just after FROM in the SQL)when the table is keys right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this particular query is failing is because 'key' is a reserved word in mysql.

FROM keys t0 WHERE t0.key = ? LIMIT 1'

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

So I'm guessing you didn't have this working before you did your orm change?

Rename the property to something like value.  $key->value reads better than $key->key anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting tables and column names needs to be done explicitly using ticks in the definition, e.g:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`key`", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
protected $key;
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words